# win32api.dll Will Not Install

Tags: python, windows, dll, twisted, buildbot

I am trying to start a Buildbot Buildslave on a Windows XP virtual machine:

```
python buildbot start .

ImportError: No module named win32api.
```

Google tells me that win32api is win32api.dll.  I downloaded the file from www.dll-files.com and followed the guide found on that site (http://www.dll-files.com/unzip.php).  When I try to run regvr32 win32api.dll, it tells me that the specified module could not be found.

tl;dr - Where do I put win32api.dll so Windows will install it?  Am I trying to use the wrong file?  (using python version 2.6)

Comment: You may want to try this question over at http://serverfault.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

win32api belongs [Python for Windows extensions](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/), Aka Pywn32.
have u installed it?

Answer (score 0):

Install ActivePython (http://www.activestate.com/activepython/) - it's a Python distro that comes bundled with the Windows dlls.  It's what everyone else does.